# How to create sharper images with UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

When I take a photo from UIImagePickerController, the camera focuses, and when a picture is taken, it is immediately very blurry. Is there a way to change the statements used in the method in order to produce a sharper image?

```
#pragma mark - Image picker delegate methods

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
// Resize the image from the camera
UIImage *scaledImage = [image resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:CGSizeMake(photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
// Crop the image to a square 
UIImage *croppedImage = [scaledImage croppedImage:CGRectMake((scaledImage.size.width -photo.frame.size.width)/2, (scaledImage.size.height -photo.frame.size.height)/2, photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height)];
// Show the photo on the screen
photo.image = croppedImage;

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

photo.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);

}
```

Comment: The PHImageManager will resize and crop a chosen photo for you, probably a lot better than however you are doing it now.

Comment: what size are you resizing it to?

Comment: @bshirley Setting it to a thumbnail that can also be touched and expanded to be viewed full size.